# How to define a dynamic filter for a custom field?

Tags: api, mantis, bubble.io

I'm connecting to bubble.io using MANTIS BUG TRACKER REST API but I want the API to retun only issues matching a value for a custom field, but the value needs to be a parameter.

Example:
I have a custom field named clients. I want the API to return all issues where clients match "paying", but "paying" is a parameter in the API call. It can be "paying", "returning", "closed", etc.

I tried using custom filters but I can only assign a single value for clients that way per filter.
Ex:
`/mantis/api/rest/issues?filter_id=1181&page_size=10&page=1`

I hope I can get a way to make that call, filtering the custom field with the API parameter.

Edit:
I tried using the following -

```
api/rest/issues?custom_field_id=59&custom_field_value=paying
```

But I'm getting about 83 issues when I should be getting only 1.
I'm sure the field_id is correct, I checked it in Mantis custom field manager.

Answer (score 0):

As of MantisBT 2.25.7, it is unfortunately not possible to do what you want using the REST API.

- *issues* endpoint does not let you search based on custom criteria
- *filters* endpoint does not have a method to create a new filter.

So for the time being you're stuck with static filters.